# Spring Webservice with multiple schemas

Tags: spring-ws

I have two schema file Schema1.xsd and Schemas2.xsd and want to create a spring webservice based on this two schemas. From Client side Werservice will be called like public operation(Schema1, Schema2). In the endpoint I have used payloadrequest, how I can specify two payloadrequest. Also I have two schemas with different complextype, how I can specify multiple request/response in requestSuffix and responseSuffix.

Comment: what have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: I have created a spring ws with existing single schema file. I am performing a upgrade where in a legacy code is upgraded to spring  and webservice is through which application can be accessed. My existing demo spring ws application with one schema file is working fine, where I have created WSDL dynamically based on single schema. But in actual legacy code there are two schema files and I tried to implement the same in my demo application. I have added commonXMLSchema in my maven dependencies but if I want to use two schema files to generate single WSDL , how I can do that?

Comment: Also both schema files have different types which I need to specify in requestSuffix and responseSuffix tag in spring-servlet.xml to override default behavior, how I can specify different types from two schemas in spring-servlet.xml